# How to detect the Task Scheduler trying to terminate a program due to the "Stop if the computer switches to battery power" option

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-task-scheduler

### Background

I am writing a PowerShell script that runs from Windows Task Scheduler and resides in the task tray.

### Problem

When you create a new task in Task Scheduler, the option `Start the task only if the computer is on AC power` and `Stop if the computer switches to battery power` are on by default.
But I don't want to stop the script when the AC adapter is plugged off. So I want to detect the Task Scheduler trying to stop the script when it switches to battery power and let the user set these options off.

### Question

In a PowerShell script, is there any way to detect the Task Scheduler trying to terminate the script due to the "Stop if the computer switches to battery power" option?

Answer (score 1):

You can likely detect that it is has happened, but you can probably only stop it from happening by changing the options on the scheduled task.

There should be an entry in the Task Scheduler's event log when a task is stopped due to battery power switches, and another when tasks are not started due to not being on AC power.

Since I type this on a desktop, I don't have easy access to what those event IDs would be.

I'd create a test task and see what the event IDs are, and then, if you'd like, you could create a scheduled task that triggers on either of those events.